# Where is my main menu?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menubar

The menu works fine.  GenerateMember is on.  The problem is that I'm trying to manipulate it in code (to put in a few dynamic items) and I can't find it.

MainMenuStrip is `null`.  Menu is `null`.  It can't be in controls because it doesn't inherit from a `Control`.

Where is it???

Just to make it clear:  I'm looking to find the menu via code, not by simply knowing the name of the component.  I want to take any form passed in and find it.

Comment: Where are you using the menu? If you use it before it's initialized (`InitializeComponent()`, at least in VB.NET), it will be `null`. e.g. You couldn't assign it to a class member immediately.

Comment: It's right there!!! Can't you see it!?!? Come on. How are we supposed to give you an answer when you don't provide enough information?

Comment: Look at your .designer.cs file and see where the declaration is. You say GenerateMember is true, but if something has corrupted the designer it may still putting the declaration in InitializeComponent() (which is what it does when GenerateMember is false). The designer is far from perfect. These things do happen. Sometimes you just have to delete it and start again.

Comment: It's in the designer, no problem.  My problem is finding it runtime--the same routine needs to run on multiple forms so I want to *FIND* it instead of looking it up by name.

Comment: The menu won't be there on multiple forms, just on one. As others have suggested, post the code where you try to access the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this (assuming only one `MenuStrip`):

```
public static MenuStrip FindMenuStrip(Form fromForm) {
  return fromForm.Controls.OfType<MenuStrip>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```